# No puedo lanzar excepción dentro del operador ternario

Tags: javascript, excepciones, operador-ternario

tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
getDatos(){ 
        let msj;
        (this.escuderia == undefined || this.piloto == undefined || this.posicion == undefined) 
        ? (msj = `Faltan Datos!` //aqui deberia ir el throw)
        : (msj = `Escuderia: ${this.escuderia}, Piloto: ${this.piloto}, Posicion: ${this.posicion}`)
        return msj
    }
```

lo que quiero en caso de que se cumpla la condición me lance un mensaje de error utilizando throw pero no puedo hacerlo, me tira errores de sintaxis y no se porque.
Lo que hago es:

```
 ? (throw "mensajedeerror")
```

intento hacer eso en lugar de guardar el msj en una variable y el VSCode me tira errores de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador ternario espera dos expresiones que retornen algo, `throw` no cumple esa condición. En todo caso esa lógica es compleja de leer, se podría reescribir así el código:

```
getDatos(){ 
    if(this.escuderia == undefined || this.piloto == undefined || this.posicion == undefined) 
       throw 'Faltan datos'
    return `Escuderia: ${this.escuderia}, Piloto: ${this.piloto}, Posicion: ${this.posicion}`
}
```

Si se quiere usar el `throw` en forma ternario se puede encerrar en una función y ejecutarla si la condición se cumple:

```
getDatos(){ 
    let msj;
    (this.escuderia == undefined || this.piloto == undefined || this.posicion == undefined) 
    ? (function(){throw 'faltan datos'}())
    : (msj = `Escuderia: ${this.escuderia}, Piloto: ${this.piloto}, Posicion: ${this.posicion}`)
    return msj
}
```